# Hide input parameters partially on activeadmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, activeadmin

I have an activeadmin form, in which one of the inputs fields is populated by json data returned by some method as

```
  f.input :tag, :label => 'Tags', :as => :select, :collection => HelperClass.get_json()
```

The json looks like this:

```
            {
                "group_name": "Group1",
                "categories": [
                  {
                    "category_name": "cat_1",
                    "score": "120"
                  },
                  {
                    "category_name": "cat_2",
                    "score": "120"
                  }
                ]
              }
```

While this is shown on the form in the UI, I want only the 'group_name' to appear. However, I would want to use the data in 'categories' later on.

Is there anyway I could do this? For eg, hide the remaining json from the form, or parse the json in some other place using 'group_name', or any other way that I can't think of..

**PS: Could you also elaborate while you answer this. I am not a ROR developer, but had to modify the code written by someone else.**

Comment: Try `HelperClass.get_json().slice(:group_name)`. This will only show group name

Answer (score 0):

First convert to array/hash then use Ruby Array/Hash methods.  Assuming you meant the JSON is an array of groups:

```
data = JSON.parse HelperClass.get_json()
f.input :tag, :label => 'Tags', :as => :select,
        :collection => data.map {|grp| grp['group_name']}
```

I suspect you want a multi-level select, which will require you to write your own JavaScript to populate the second select.  Maybe https://github.com/blocknotes/activeadmin_selectize will help with that.

Comment: yes. the map seems to be helping show only the group_name. it was the remaining data that i wanted to access. I'll check out the JS part now. Thanks anyway!